# Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex with PERL v5.10.1

Tags: regex, perl

Issue: Unrecognized escape \m passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/.*?/ at ./build.pl line 890.

```
856 sub addProperity {
857 
858     my ($line,$inprop,$newpom,$depver,$artifactId,$thisartifactId,$br,$paramvalue,$masterpomversion) = @_;
859 
860     my $alllines;
861 
862     if ( $$inprop ) {
863 
864             (my $thisline = $line) =~ s!\r!!;
865             chomp $thisline;
866 
867             $thisline =~ s%<!--.*?-->%%g;
868             $thisline =~ s%<!--.*%%;
869             $thisline =~ s%.*-->%%;
870 
871             $$inprop = '' if ( $thisline =~ m!</properties>! );
872             $thisline =~ s%<.{0,1}properties>%%g;
873             $thisline =~ s%\s*$%%;
874 
875             while ( $thisline ) {
876                 #print "thisline=$thisline"."XX\n";
877                 ( my $propname = $thisline ) =~ s!\s*<(.*?)>.*!$1!;
878                 if ( $propname =~ m!.group\s*! ) {
879 
880                 (my $propvalue = $thisline ) =~ s!.*<$propname>(.*?)</$propname>.*!$1!;
881                 if ( $propvalue =~ /\s*com.alcatel.axs.(.*)\s*/ ) {
882 
883                     my $groupId=$1;
884                     my $thisversion=getThisVersion($depver,$groupId,$artifactId,$thisartifactId,$br,$paramvalue,$masterpomversion);
885                     push ( @{$newpom}, '<'.$propname.'.repversion>'.$thisversion.'</'.$propname.'.repversion>'."\n");
886                 }
887             }
888 
889             my $currentline=$thisline;
890             $thisline =~ s!.*?</$propname>!!;
891             last if ($currentline=$thisline);
892         }
893     }
894 }
```

Background:

The script was working fine on - Perl v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi, but

Not working on Perl - v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: If you believe it helpful to try:  Can you reproduce the same error in a much shorter test script?  Why or why not?  Suppose a very short script which does nothing but to eliminate characters with the specified property and then to print out the text that remains.  (Incidentally, is there a reason line 890 does not use the `/g` -- or, in your case, `!g` -- pattern modifier?)

Comment: Looks like `\m` is put into `$propname` from `$line`. Then it gets embeded into regexp without quoting. What is actually in `$thisline` before it fails?

Comment: $thisline = 'something   ?</apc.app.fwk\components\apc-a7324-plug\src\main\resource\plugin.xml>';

Comment: You may solve your problem by escaping meta characters (such as backslash) with either quotemeta or `\Q .. \E`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is simply that the string in `$propname` contains the characters `\m`.

If you really mean it to contain a backslash (and I would guess not as it looks like you're working with XML tags) then you need to write

```
$thisline =~ s!.*?</\Q$propname\E>!!
```

to escape any metacharacters in the variable

Comment: thanks very much which has worked but, it complains from other suroutine.  Use of uninitialized value in regexp compilation at ./build.pl line 1025.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./build.pl line 1026.